# FQL checkin table query throws a parser error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I wrote the following FQL query which should work but it seems to fail:

```
SELECT coords, tagged_uids, page_id FROM checkin 
WHERE author_uid = IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

It throws an error as follows:

> Parser error: unexpected 'IN' at position 68.

Doesn't make any sense when other queries of similar syntax work fine like this one:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Anyone know a better way to get the check-ins from my friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN` should replace the `=` operator, and you only need one. Try:

```
SELECT coords, tagged_uids, page_id FROM checkin 
WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Also, make sure you have the [`friends_checkins`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) extended permission.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this might work for me! Too bad I can't filter by page_id...once I add that to the query it throes an exception.

Comment: That's weird, because `page_id` is indexable too. What are you trying to query with that?